# Sending params in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

How can I send a `params[:age]` in:

```
=link_to "Delete", [@contest, claim], title: "Delete", method: :delete, confirm: "Sure?", class: "noborder", remote: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's params works only in rails 2 and 4.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/PolymorphicRoutes

Answer (score 1):

You can pass hash with params as last element of path array:

```
= link_to '...', [@contest, claim, {age: 33}]
```

UPDATE: Seems it's possible in rails 4+ only. Try `polymorphic_path`

```
= link_to '...', polymorphic_path([@contest, claim], age: 33)
```

Answer (score 1):

if your passing value itself is `params[:age]` then you can send like this:

```
= link_to '...', [@contest, claim, {age: params[:age]}]
```